# tensorflow TFRecords cannot parse serialized example

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am getting the following error when trying to decode a TFRecord example :

> InvalidArgumentError: Name: , Feature: relevance (data type:
>   float) is required but could not be found. [Op:ParseExample]

To decode the example, I am using `tf.io.parse_example` as follows

```
example_features = tf.compat.v1.io.parse_example(
     tf.reshape(serialized_list, [-1]), peritem_feature_spec)
```

where `serialized_list` looks like

```
[ <example_object>, ...
b'\n\xcc\x01\n\x15\n\trelevance\x12\x08\x12\x06\n\x04\x9a\xe9`D\n\xb2
\x01\n\x13encoded_clust_index\x12\x9a\00\ <more...>]
```

and `peritem_feature_spec` looks like

```
peritem_feature_spec = {
    'relevance':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
    'encoded_clust_index':tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32)
    }
```

I'm very confused why the feature 'relevance' can't be found.  I think I encoded and created my TFRecord objects correctly.  Am I creating the feature_spec incorrectly?  My thought is `tf.VarLenFeature` is the incorrect feature type to use, but I cannot figure out what is correct.

Using `tensorflow_ranking.python.data.parse_from_example_in_example` is able to correctly decode the TFRecord into its features, but I don't know why `tf.io.parse_example` fails

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : My old answer is below this answer

The right answer was to provide a `default_value` to the feature spec

```
peritem_feature_spec = {
    'relevance':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32, default_value=0.0),
    'encoded_clust_index':tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32, default_value=0.0)
    }
```

My **old** (works, but incorrect) answer is below

So the issue came down to how my features were being padded in the tensorflow_ranking library. It was padding a list feature like :

```
def pad_fn():
    return tf.pad(
        tensor=serialized_list,
        paddings=[[0, 0], [0, list_size -cur_list_size]],
            constant_values="")
```

This method appends empty bytes to the end of the tensor.  The parser looks for a `feature_name` in the empty tensors, and responds that it cant find it.  My workaround was to append serialized TFRecord example protos instead of an empty byte string.  I accomplished this like so :

```
def pad_fn():
    # Create feature spec for tf.train.Example to append
    pad_spec = {}
    # Default values are 0 or an empty byte string depending on 
    # original serialized data type
    dtype_map = {tf.float32:tf.train.Feature(
            float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[0.0])), 
                 tf.int32:tf.train.Feature(
                         int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[0])), 
                 tf.string:tf.train.Feature(
                         bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(
                                 value=[bytes('', encoding='UTF-8')]))}
     # Create the feature spec
    for key, item in peritem_feature_spec.items():
        dtype = item.dtype
        pad_spec[key] = dtype_map[dtype]
    # Make and serialize example to append
    constant_values = tf.train.Example(
            features=tf.train.Features(feature=pad_spec))
    constant_val_str = constant_values.SerializeToString()

    # Add serialized padding to end of list
    return tf.pad(
        tensor=serialized_list,
        paddings=[[0, 0], [0, list_size - cur_list_size]],
        constant_values=constant_val_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `VarLenFeature` can you try `tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.float32, allow_missing = True ,default_value=0)` explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/FixedLenSequenceFeature) and see if that works?